# call or send message to activity when thread is started in background service

Tags: android

I need to show some progress bar with some message in the activity thats already running from a background thread. thread should notify this activity when thread is started and finished. Please let me know whats the best approach and need to have a good solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Put your background task in the `doInBackground` function, and update the progress bar in the `onProgressUpdate` function, which will be invoked on the UI thread.